# Related lists layout changes on refresh for partner users in experience cloud

Tags: related-list, guest-user, partner, cloud, experience

i have a lightning data table and if the user clicks the hyper link of a record it redirects them to the record detail page of that object , but in the related lists its only displaying 3 columns but upon refresh am getting 4 columns displayed for partner users in experience cloud,The 4 columns should display by default any time we open a record. please let me know if you have any solutions regarding this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.